# PyCharm Keyboard Shortcut To Help Opening Existing Scratches

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Pycharm's scratches are useful.
Opening new scratches is easy (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Insert).
If one wishes to open an existing scratch file and it's still in the recently edited file list one may use Ctrl+E, however if not it seems that the path is to grab the mouse, expand the docked project pane, switch from "Project" (or wherever else you may be) to "Scratches", then navigate to the right file.

Does anyone have a keyboard-driven way to access existing scratches that I've not considered?